# Calculate exact solution to maximize cosine

Tags: trigonometry

For a constant, `N`, what value of `x` will maximize the cosine (or any trig) function?

\begin{equation}
1 = \cos{(Nx)}
\end{equation}

I am looking for the exact form, not the approximation because,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\arccos{(1)}}{N} = x = 0
\end{equation}

For example, [WolframAlpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%3D+cos%2819.013+%2a+x%29) states that if `N = 19.013`, then,
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{2000 \pi n}{19013} , n \text{ } \varepsilon \text{ } \text{set of integers}
\end{equation}
How was that solution calculated?

Comment: How do you maximize an equation?  You can _solve_ an equation.  The solution comes from examining the set of angles with cosine 1, which you can figure out by looking at the unit circle.

Comment: I am solving for when cosine is maximized which is one

Comment: Try first the case N=1, then N=2, then see if you can decide the general process.  (Polya: if you cannot answer a question, there is a simpler question you also cannot answer.  Answer that one first)

Comment: It is true the maximum value of cosine is 1, do you know for what x cosine attains its maximum?

Comment: @WWright, `cosine(pi) = 1` but I need to solve this in terms of `N`

Comment: Maybe there's a value of $x$ that works for all $N$?

Comment: I have just a quick note on your equation stating, \begin{equation}
x = \frac{2000 \pi n}{19013} , n \text{ } \varepsilon \text{ } \text{set of integers}
\end{equation}

You should typically $\in$ (\in) rather than $\varepsilon$. Also, to make the $\mathbb{Z}$ symbol, you type \mathbb{Z}. The reason I mention this is because I used to typeset the symbols as you have above and then realized the proper $\LaTeX$ code to get what I want.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto  $\cos\left(\pi\right)=-1$ but $\cos\left(0\right)=1$ and cosine is a periodic function, do you see where to take it from here?

Comment: Use binary search.

Comment: -1...please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosine takes it's maximum when the argument is $2k\pi$, where $k$ is any integer. Therefore

$$\begin{aligned}2k\pi = Nx \\\\

x=\frac{2k\pi}{N}\end{aligned}$$

Thus for $N=19.013$
$$x= \frac{2k\pi}{19.013} = \frac{2000k\pi}{19013}$$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that

\begin{equation}
1 = \cos{(2\pi)}
\end{equation}

Therefore, for a given `N` to "maximize" cosine:
\begin{aligned}
2\pi = Nx \
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
x = \frac{2\pi}{N}
\end{aligned}

Using the above equation:
\begin{aligned}
x &= \frac{2\pi}{19.013} \
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
x &\approx 0.33046 \
\end{aligned}

Comment: The WolframAlpha answer is more general, but only because it accounts for the fact that cos(t) = 1 for t every even multiple of pi (including zero).

Answer (score 0):

$x=0$ is always a solution, since $\cos(N\times0)=\cos0=1$ .

If you want the set of all solutions, use the fact that

$$\cos\theta=1 \Leftrightarrow \theta=2k\pi \text{ with } k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Replacing $\theta$ by $Nx$ above gives you the set of solutions :

$$ 1=\cos{Nx}\Leftrightarrow x\in \left\{\frac{2k\pi}N\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$$

This is the solution given by Wolfram Alpha for $N=19.013=\frac{19013}{1000}$.